# PHP - parenthesis before variable usage

Tags: php

I would like to know more about something I see more than a few times in PHP, what are it's uses and if it's still used in current PHP version, or an echo (no pun intended..) from the past, and if there are other/better practices today.

So let's take this function (shortened for brevity):

```
public function apiResource($name, $controller, array $options = []){}
```

- Why is `$options`'s parameter type set to accept array and also prefixed with array?

And here:

```
$only = ['index', 'show', 'store', 'update', 'destroy'];
if (isset($options['except'])) {
    $only = array_diff($only, (array) $options['except']);
}
```

- `$options['except']` is an array within the `$options` array, if that key didn't hold an array, it would throw an error in anycase, so what is the purpose of prefixing this variable with an `(array)` type?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is specifying that `$options` is of type array, and if not set, setting it to an empty array. It's not being declared twice, only clarified that it excepts an array only for `$options`.

```
public function apiResource($name, $controller, array $options = []){}
```

Your second question:

```
...(array) $options['except']
```

It's forcing `$options['except']` NOT `$options` to an array. Remember `['except' => 'string']` is valid as `$options`, but `$options['except']` is not an array in this case.

Comment: Hey FrankerZ, re Q1: You didn't really clarify why both `= []` and `(array)`, while only one of them serves the purpose, no need to state the obvious ("it accepts an array only for `$options`" => of course it does)

Q2 - please confirm: `array_dif` accepts 2 array params, so `(array) $options['except']` would create an empty array, if it doesn't exist, and if it does, will leave it be?

Comment: Q1: Declaring the parameter as an array, and setting a default value are 2 different things. Q2: Yes. If in doubt, head to https://3v4l.org/ and try it out. `var_dump()` Is your friend.

Comment: The main reason for declaring `$options` as an array in the parameter list is so that if someone tried to call the function with a value which wasn't an array e.g. `$x = apiResource($name, $controller, 'xyz');` PHP will flag an error and exit.